# CRC checksum using long (64 bit)

Tags: c, checksum

I have checked different implementations of CRC64. For example, [this](http://code.google.com/p/turningpolyhedron/source/browse/trunk/turningpolyhedron/SolverTest2/crc64.cpp?spec=svn202&r=202), [this](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/coverage/org.jacoco.core/org.jacoco.core.internal.data/CRC64.java.html) and [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/259177-crc64-calculate-the-cyclic-redundancy-check/). The problem with all these is that they work with bytes. However, on a 64 bit system, I would like to work with `long` (8 bytes). In this way, I will need to iterate less. For example, for data of 128 bytes, using a `byte`, I need to iterate 128 times, while with `long`, I would need to iterate only 16 times.

Is there any CRC64 implementation that use `long` or even a word size greater than a byte? Can these schemes be modified to do so?

Comment: If SSE is available, GCC is most likely to unroll your loop and even use 128 bit XMM registers if possible. So before you spend tons of time blindly optimizing the code - check what your compiler is doing.

Comment: Ya, but the computation is cyclic, which I don't think can be vectorized.

Comment: Before you try to outsmart the compiler, check how smart it is. GCC performs many loop analysis, some of them I am sure you never heard of. It can (and in fact does, under certain circumstances) unroll a loop even for cyclic computation. I am not saying it does in your case, but you have to check before proceeding with your own optimizations.

Comment: Premature optimization is the source of enormous amounts of trouble. Always make sure that you really need more performance _and_ that what you have now isn't optimal first...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CRC calculation uses a trick to avoid having to process the data bit-by-bit: It uses a lookup table which allows it to process multiple bits at once.

Processing `n` bits at once requires a lookup table of size `2^n`. The implementations you linked read 1 byte (8 bits) at a time, and indeed they all use a lookup table of size 256 == 2^8.

Processing 64 bits at a time would require a lookup table of size 2^64, which is not practical. This is why common implementations of CRC do the processing 1 byte at a time.

While it's possible to process 2 bytes at a time using a 65536-entry array, this is likely to have a negative performance impact due to using more CPU cache memory.

Comment: BTW, do you know if lookup tables are used in hardware implementations as well?

Comment: @Vlad I don't know much about hardware implementations.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: There are hardware implementations that are linked with serial communications and run at the same speed as the baud rate, processing each bit in turn and so don't need lookup tables.